# Need to know how to make python window close with keypress

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a complete beginner and I was making a quick 2-sec code but I need to know how to make the window close with the press of a key(any) here is my code right now:

## Hack

```
print("Welcome to the CIA Honeycombed password center type the first password to continue")

password = input("Enter your password")

if password == "CIA":
        print("Access Granted")
else:
        print("Access Denied")
input("Press ENTER to exit the program")
```

Comment: what issues do you have with your current code? Is the issue that you have to press Enter to exit but you want to exit on *any* key? Your code doesn't open any windows—do you want to try closing the window created by an ancestor process instead? (note: it is not necessary that such ancestor even exists) where do you run your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to close the window you can use the following code for python 3.x:

```
import os
import signal
import time

print("Welcome to the CIA Honeycombed password center type the first password to continue")

password = input("Enter your password")

if password == "CIA": 
    print("Access Granted") 
    time.sleep(10)
else: 
    print("Access Denied") 
    key = input("Press ENTER to exit the program")

    os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

You can save this code to a file named `cia.py` and then run it via a terminal by using `python3 cia.py`. I also added a `time.sleep` so that it does not closes immediately after typing the correct password.

I am using OSX, and this terminated my terminal task, but did not close the window initially. This behavior can be changed in terminal preferences, by choosing to close the terminal window if it exits cleanly:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but it says this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\Documents\hack basic.py", line 5, in <module>
    password = raw_input("Enter your password")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: change raw_input to input, as you had it before

Comment: oh yeah, and for some reason it runs with python shell and not CMD

Comment: oh god sorry, it's python 3.5

Comment: Hmmm, it should work similarly. I updated the code. Working with python 3 now.

Comment: I saved the script in a file `cia.py` and run it via terminal, by using `python3 cia.py`. If the wrong password is typed, it closes the window.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eugene\Documents\hack basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGHUP)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP' is what it says???? I have no idea what that means

Comment: Change it for `signal.SIGTERM` if you are on windows

Comment: Any time! glad i could help!

Comment: wait... when I right the right password it closes super fast

Comment: Did you type it with shift?

Comment: The password is shift

Comment: CIA is the password

Comment: Great, you can also use `input` or `time.sleep`. I added the time code so that it closes in some seconds.